# Filter messages through a Rest response in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

I am new to Spring Integration

**Context**

We have a CTI system (CSTA Server, Call Center Web Application)
I have to check if an agent is logged in our contact center (by Restful API) and forward every CSTA server(webSocket) Event from logged in Agents.

I am able to get all events from the CSTA server asynchronously 
(tcp-connection-factory / tcp-inbound-channel-adapter) 
and if necessary transform them (ex. JSON).

The event has unique agent identifiers which i could use to check through our API if an agent is logged in and than dispatch the message to an Endpoint.
I dont want to dispatch the reply from the Rest service rather i would like to dispatch every csta event that as a logged in agent.

I able to consume an http outbound-gateway  from a Rest Service. How can i enrich a Message or filter depending on the reply i will get from an http outbound-gateway?

In short: I want to filter (depending on the reply of a rest service) every message from a websocket and dispatch it to another endpoint.

Are there any git examples i could look at?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need a [`Router`](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/MessageRouter.html) pattern for your purpose:

```
<int:router input-channel="input" ref="myRouter" method="route"/>
```

And [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/applications/cafe/cafe-si) you can find a Cafe sample.

Comment: While i get the routing pattern i still dont know how to enrich a message through a gateway. In the Cafe sample the routing is based on the payload (hot-/cold-drinks) of the order. 
The events i am trying to route are missing this kind of information and have to be enriched bevor routing.

Is something like this possible?

`<int:header-enricher id="enricher" input-channel="input" 
output-channel="output"> <int:header name="loggedIn" 
expression="call the gateway service ">
</int:header> 
</int:header-enricher> `

Comment: Yep... this is possible. But since `3.0` the `<enricher>` can populate headers as well. That would be easier for you to call external service from there using just `request-channel`. Take a look to this article too: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/Enriching-Headers-Using-Gateways